# Why I am getting a popup when I hover my cursor over a particular word in ms word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

This image is showing popup when I hover cursor over a particular word.
It is not hyperlink. I want to know whats happening there.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think that is something in your document. Word does not do that on any machine here. Make a new, blank Word document. Type in a short paragraph of bland text - nothing fancy at all. Any pop-ups?

Comment: That is an Endnote created from within Word.

Comment: Where did you get the Word document?

Answer (score 0):

### That is a Footnote or Endnote created from within Word.

If you click on it, it should take you to the Footnote/Endnote, itself. It may take a Ctrl+Click. Another way to do a pop-up is using the AutoTextList field, but that will not give the little icon.

I believe it to be a Footnote simply because by default, Footnotes are assigned Ababic numerals and Endnotes are given Roman numerals.